# How to secure a node.js web api with Azure AD and consume it with a React.js frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-active-directory

This is what i have at the moment :

- A React.JS web application which signs in the user to azure ad with the tenant. I'm using https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal/ for the sign in. With the user authenticated, I am able to get user information from the Microsoft Graph API
- A Node.JS Web API which accesses the database. The routes are not secured with Azure AD as yet

What i'm trying to understand/implement :
 - The React.JS web app passes the user token for each request to the Web API
 - The Web API validates the azure AD token before sending the response

My question now is: Is this actually the right way to do it ? I've tried this sample from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-nodejs-webapi but i'm not sure what kind of token it is suppose to accept.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Basically you can make your API accept the Id token given to your front-end. It can be a quick way of doing authentication. The "proper" approach would be to register your API as a separate application and then use its Application ID URI to get an access token for it, and then using that in the calls, similar to how you work with MS Graph API.

Comment: Thank you juunas for your quick answer, I indeed intended on implementing the "proper" approach. So from what you are saying, I don't need a user to be authenticated to get an access token ? Is the Microsoft sample I mentionned above using this access token ?

Comment: The front-end will definitely need a logged-in user, though your back-end can get a refresh token if it exchanges the access token it receives for access tokens to other APIs. So the front-end cannot act by itself, but the back-end can, even on behalf of a user, assuming you get a refresh token.

Comment: And yes, that sample API is designed to receive an access token acquired using the API's client id as the resource.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, the only difference its that my client is a react-native app. I was able to login and get a Token from azure AD, now I need to authorize the use of my Node API using this token. Were you able to make your system work ?